# JS document.getElementById() with Int

Tags: javascript, html, django-templates, cross-browser

I am getting some `DOM elements` by `document.getElementById({{templete_var}})`  the `{{templete_var}}` can be an `Int`. I would like to know if this can cause any errors across different browsers/devices. It works fine on Firefox (ubuntu) and Safari (Mac) but are there maybe mobile browsers where this could cause an error?

Here a little code snippet to make it clear what I mean.
In the code snippet both methods work.

```js
// 1 and 2 would be template variables here so I can't "hardcode" them
document.getElementById(1).style.color = "blue"
document.getElementById("2").style.color = "red"
```

```html
<span id="1">first text</span><br>
<span id="2">other text</span>
```

Surprisingly I could not find anything on this topic, if this is a duplicate please link the original.

Comment: "I could not find anything on this topic" https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute In other words, there's no restriction except "at least one character, must not contain spaces"

Comment: Keep in mind that if you also use the `id` as a selector in css, it can't start with a number. So if your css includes this line: `#1 { color: red; } #2 { color: blue; }`, it won't work. So technically it's adviced to always start an elements id with a character. It might not matter now, but if in the future you want to switch to using a css file instead of inline changing of the color, the id can't be `1`. So although for javascript and DOM, elements can start with a number, for css it can't. Which might explain the issues you have with other browsers.

Comment: Anyway, can't you just prefix the `id`s? Like `whatever_{{template_var}}`?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca The prefix idea is good, I think I will go with this and thanks for the Info material. 
@ Shilly Thanks for the comment, luckily css isn't a problem here. I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Lets see, the syntax of the document query `document.getElementById` only accepts a string value as parameter. (See [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) ) . It could be that a couple of user agents (browsers) are "smart" and convert internally the integer (1) to ("1"). But you CANT and SHOULDNT rely on that. Hence the solution is to force the convertion to string.

```js
const foo = 1;
const bar = '2';

document.getElementById(''+ foo).style.color = "blue"; 
document.getElementById('' + bar).style.color = "red";
```

```html
<span id="1">first text</span><br> 
<span id="2">other text</span>
```

In those 2 queries both variables will be forced to be strings, `foo` will be converted to "1" and `bar` will just keep being "2".

Comment: That's not what's being asked. They're asking whether numeric ids are a problem.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca well the basic syntax allows only string, the only solution considering possible cross-browser issues is to convert the number to a string.

Comment: Again, that's not what's being asked. The question is whether, e.g. `document.getElementById("1")` is problematic, not if `getElementById` accepts numbers as parameters.

Comment: How can a completely normal document query like `document.getElementById("1") ` be problematic? He is facing the problem that the template delivers the variable as an integer, and getElementById behavior is different across browsers because of that. Hence the solution : convert it to an STRING!. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: While it's not so clear from the question (I still have my doubts about what exactly is being asked), I'm starting to think you may be in part right. Please, do some micro-edit to your answer so I can remove the downvote.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Done. I hope its clear enough now.

Answer (score 0):

well why not make it .toString() of whatever id you're getting?

Comment: as pointed out before, its more about if an Int can cause a Problem. There are a lot of solutions to make sure the function does not fail but its more about if the method i am using is safe...